# Woocommerce add attribute value names as class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to set the attribute value names of a product attribute as classname for each `<span>` item.

So I can set eg `material` as product attribute. And then attach values like `stone`, `paper` etc.

How can I set `stone` and `paper` as a classname? Normally values are printed like -> `Material: stone, paper`. I want to set a classname so I can change stone and paper to a small image.

So in `woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php` I have added this:

```
<?php
 if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {
   $values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );        

    ///////////////this is added//////////////////////////  
    if($attribute['name'] == 'pa_material'){ // I only want to set a classname if attribute name == material            

     foreach($values as $value){ 
        $value_classname = $value; // how can I get the value name??
     }                    
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize('<span class="lbl ' . $value_classname . '">'. implode( '</span><span class="lbl ' . $value . '">', $values ).'</span>' ) ), $attribute, $values );
    //////////////////////////////////////////// 
    } else{
      echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );

    }

 } else {

// Convert pipes to commas and display values
   $values = array_map( 'trim', explode( WC_DELIMITER, $attribute['value'] ) );
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );

}
?>
```

Right now the classname returns blank obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the attribute values assigned to the product for just the material attribute:

```
global $product;
//this will get the names
$values = wc_get_product_terms($product->id, 'pa_material', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
```